# How to develop a website like github

Tags: html, iframe, web, github, history

I find many sites use the div instead of iframe, I know how to load a page by `$.load`, but there are some problems.

Like many sites, there is a nav bar in my page. All sites will be shown with it.

1. I use a div to instead iframe in my page, then use `$.load()` to load the target page. so, the url in browser will never been modified. Users can't bookmark current page.
2. Since step 1, I use `window.history` with the new api, I can forward or back to a page with refresh partly.
3. As you know, the target page was load by ajax. When a user foward to the target page by input the url in browser, which will get a page without the nav bar.

**Here's my problem**:how can i solve the problem in step 3.
also, I'd like to know how Github works

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Can you clarify the question and fix the spacing and capitalization issues so this is readable?

Comment: sorry...i just want to know how the github works.it always refreshes partly.

Comment: and there's no iframe or frameset in gitbug.how do they implements it.use a tag like jsp's include or use ajax to request the nav page?

Comment: github sends a full page if you go directly to a page (#3), and sends partial content when AJAX + `history.pushState` is loading the page.

Comment: ok,i can't understand how they implements it .for example.if my url is http://github/a/b/c.html(redirectly),how the c.html get the nav bar like other pages.use include?

Answer (score 0):

github heavily uses pjax for inline page loading: http://pjax.heroku.com/

Comment: i viewed this page ,but it didn't soluve my problem.for example ,i hava a main.html,content1.html,content2.html. if i forward to content1.html through main.html by pjax,it works. but if i load content1.html directly,it hava not the main.html's nav or other content.